# How to add an axis break in Chart.js like the ones pictured below?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have several graphs where the y-axis starts at a nonzero number and I want an indicator to make this clear. Is there a way to add breaks on the axis? [Line Axis Break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaSyJ.png)

I'm not really even sure what the correct term for these axis breaks are.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this with chart.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.